# Keeping track of random number and stopping loop

Tags: python, loops, random

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get my program to keep track of the total of the random numbers im generating and getting my program to stop when the numbers add up to a specific value.

```
for x in range(0,times):
###but maybe a while loop?

    table=[0 for i in range (21)]
    import random 
    for d1 in range(21):
        if table1[d1]: 
           table[d1] = random.expovariate(gamma_val)
        else:
           table[d1] = random.expovariate(1/gamma_val)

    mn= min(table) ####selects minimum value of table which i use in rest of program##

###program goes on to do some biology thing###
```

I would like the loop to end once the total number of mn (minimum numbers selected from table) adds up to a certain value

Comment: "numbers add up to a specific value"?  "count my random numbers"?  Please pick one of the two terminating conditions and focus on that. It may be necessary to do both, in which case, please clarify.

Comment: You probably don't want to `import random` `times` times!

Comment: Thanks, I'm selecting the lowest value of a set of random numbers. I need my loop to stop running once the total of these random number mn=10000.  But I still need to mn to be generated freshly each loop

Comment: @kbob: `mn` seems to be the **min** of these random numbers, **not the total** (aka sum).

Comment: @kbob: Please **update** the question to (1) be properly formatted and (2) actually state your actual requirements.  Please don't add comments to your question.  Please **update** your question.

Comment: "the total of the random numbers"?  "the total number of mn (minimum numbers selected from table)"?  It's hard to answer when your description of the problem has minor inconsistencies.  Please try to focus on the **actual** problem and try to state it consistently.

Comment: @S.Lott: It seems that the OP himself didn't knew what he wanted since after 45 minutes of struggling has just accepted the first answer to be posted, or maybe he just wasn't smart enough to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My crystal ball tells me you want:

```
total = 0.0
while total < 10000.0:
    ... # your code
    total += mn
```

Comment: @kbob: It was the first answer, what were you doing till now?!? *(Also if it solved your problem you should accept it!)*

Answer (score 0):

From what I've gathered you might want to try something like this:

```
import random 
table = [0.0 for i in xrange(0, 21)]
while sum(table) < 10000.0:
    for i in xrange(0, len(table)):
        if table1[i] > 0:
           table[i] = random.expovariate(gamma_val)
        else:
           table[i] = random.expovariate(1/gamma_val)
mn = min(table)
```

Key insights: import once, use loop conditions wisely.

I don't know if you're using Python 2 or Python 3, so the syntax might be different.  Also, if you could explain your problem more clearly, you would probably receive better answers.